# Excel: Count values based on Condition but omit the repetitive values

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with datetime,dayofweak,start time and end time, For example I need to find the count of dayofweak as "Sunday" with a given start time and end time on all dates where it should count it as 1 for any number of repetition in same day. I have used the following formula which counts the values with repetition on same date.

[image]

=========================Sample Data====================================

```
Open Time   DATES   day month   year    days    time
1/5/2014 1:24   1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  1:24
1/5/2014 3:05   1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  3:05
1/5/2014 2:13   1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  2:13
1/5/2014 3:10   1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  3:10
1/5/2014 8:41   1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  8:41
1/5/2014 16:27  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  16:27
1/5/2014 11:30  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  11:30
1/5/2014 12:35  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  12:35
1/5/2014 9:34   1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  9:34
1/5/2014 11:21  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  11:21
1/5/2014 10:02  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  10:02
1/5/2014 10:11  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  10:11
1/5/2014 11:01  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  11:01
1/5/2014 11:28  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  11:28
1/5/2014 12:53  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  12:53
1/5/2014 11:58  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  11:58
1/5/2014 12:19  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  12:19
1/5/2014 12:53  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  12:53
1/5/2014 17:44  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  17:44
1/5/2014 15:02  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  15:02
1/5/2014 13:01  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  13:01
1/5/2014 15:03  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  15:03
1/5/2014 15:08  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  15:08
1/5/2014 16:01  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  16:01
1/5/2014 17:00  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  17:00
1/5/2014 20:18  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  20:18
1/5/2014 16:45  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  16:45
1/5/2014 17:53  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  17:53
1/5/2014 19:55  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  19:55
1/5/2014 18:03  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  18:03
1/5/2014 19:28  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  19:28
1/5/2014 18:47  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  18:47
1/5/2014 18:54  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  18:54
1/5/2014 19:01  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  19:01
1/5/2014 19:09  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  19:09
1/5/2014 19:17  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  19:17
1/5/2014 19:32  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  19:32
1/5/2014 19:45  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  19:45
1/5/2014 19:40  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  19:40
1/5/2014 19:49  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  19:49
1/5/2014 19:59  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  19:59
1/5/2014 19:46  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  19:46
1/5/2014 19:55  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  19:55
1/5/2014 20:05  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  20:05
1/5/2014 20:46  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  20:46
1/5/2014 20:20  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  20:20
1/5/2014 20:41  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  20:41
1/5/2014 22:23  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  22:23
1/5/2014 22:13  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  22:13
1/5/2014 22:45  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  22:45
1/5/2014 22:47  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  22:47
1/5/2014 22:18  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  22:18
1/5/2014 22:28  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  22:28
1/5/2014 22:44  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  22:44
1/5/2014 22:40  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  22:40
1/5/2014 22:47  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  22:47
1/5/2014 22:55  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  22:55
1/5/2014 22:54  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  22:54
1/5/2014 22:52  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  22:52
1/5/2014 23:04  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  23:04
1/5/2014 23:05  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  23:05
1/5/2014 23:06  1/5/2014    5   1   2014    Sunday  23:06
1/12/2014 1:03  1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  1:03
1/12/2014 3:50  1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  3:50
1/12/2014 7:50  1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  7:50
1/12/2014 8:23  1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  8:23
1/12/2014 10:18 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:18
1/12/2014 10:30 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:30
1/12/2014 12:08 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  12:08
1/12/2014 8:19  1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  8:19
1/12/2014 8:33  1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  8:33
1/12/2014 10:09 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:09
1/12/2014 9:14  1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  9:14
1/12/2014 9:57  1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  9:57
1/12/2014 10:10 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:10
1/12/2014 10:12 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:12
1/12/2014 10:14 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:14
1/12/2014 10:15 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:15
1/12/2014 10:25 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:25
1/12/2014 10:17 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:17
1/12/2014 10:20 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:20
1/12/2014 11:08 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  11:08
1/12/2014 10:21 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:21
1/12/2014 10:23 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:23
1/12/2014 10:29 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:29
1/12/2014 10:29 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:29
1/12/2014 13:50 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  13:50
1/12/2014 15:59 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  15:59
1/12/2014 15:17 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  15:17
1/12/2014 10:44 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:44
1/12/2014 10:32 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:32
1/12/2014 10:36 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:36
1/12/2014 10:38 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:38
1/12/2014 10:41 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:41
1/12/2014 10:48 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:48
1/12/2014 10:55 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  10:55
1/12/2014 11:00 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  11:00
1/12/2014 11:38 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  11:38
1/12/2014 11:53 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  11:53
1/12/2014 11:47 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  11:47
1/12/2014 12:03 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  12:03
1/12/2014 12:23 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  12:23
1/12/2014 12:39 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  12:39
1/12/2014 12:38 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  12:38
1/12/2014 12:52 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  12:52
1/12/2014 13:11 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  13:11
1/12/2014 13:31 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  13:31
1/12/2014 13:20 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  13:20
1/12/2014 14:02 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  14:02
1/12/2014 14:00 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  14:00
1/12/2014 16:40 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  16:40
1/12/2014 16:56 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  16:56
1/12/2014 15:29 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  15:29
1/12/2014 16:11 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  16:11
1/12/2014 16:22 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  16:22
1/12/2014 17:00 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  17:00
1/12/2014 17:42 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  17:42
1/12/2014 17:19 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  17:19
1/12/2014 20:50 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  20:50
1/12/2014 18:44 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  18:44
1/12/2014 18:34 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  18:34
1/12/2014 18:25 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  18:25
1/12/2014 18:45 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  18:45
1/12/2014 18:44 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  18:44
1/12/2014 20:10 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  20:10
1/12/2014 18:58 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  18:58
1/12/2014 19:44 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  19:44
1/12/2014 21:25 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  21:25
1/12/2014 20:12 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  20:12
1/12/2014 21:27 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  21:27
1/12/2014 21:52 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  21:52
1/12/2014 22:40 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  22:40
1/12/2014 23:19 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  23:19
1/12/2014 22:20 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  22:20
1/12/2014 22:38 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  22:38
1/12/2014 23:29 1/12/2014   12  1   2014    Sunday  23:29
```

===========================Sample Data==================================

```
=COUNTIFS(E:E,"Sunday",F:F,">="&H2,F:F,"<="&I2)
```

Here for sunday ,from 00:00:00 to 00:59:59 i have found value with this formula, now what I need is the date should be distinct for example now the date is duplicate for starttime to endtime but now if I got one date for a time stamp then I should not be counting that date again for repetition.

Comment: have you formatted the three time columns as TIME?

Comment: @AHC Yes I have formatted. I don't have issues on the time. What I need now is my formula to count values where Day="Sunday" starttime = "0:00" and endtime="0:59" under all dates but should count only once for a particular date. Now it counts more than once for a date as the formula is like that.

Comment: the sample data given above is not sufficient, it only shows one date. try steven's answer and see if it works, otherwise, provide a representative data and expected results column.

Comment: I have added some sample data @AHC. Please have a look. Steven's Answer counts the whole values for all dates as 1.

Comment: so basically, for each day (each unique data), you want number of timestamps (on hourly basis) on each Sunday? is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a way to answer your question:

here is the [sample sheet with the answer](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cy3obh9a6gexz78/countif%20timestamp.xlsx?dl=0)
you can follow the steps in the above downloadable sheet.
here is a screen 
[image]

you need to make sure that the column H is formatted as time.

then you need to put your start/end timestamps horizontally, starting from **K** to **AH**, in two rows (start row and end row).

then you pull dynamically the unique dates from column **A** and put them in column **J** using this formula:

```
=IFNA(INDEX($A$2:$A$229730,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($J$2:J2,$A$2:$A$229730),0)),"")
```

you put this formula in **J3** and make sure that you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula.

then drag down and fill until you have all your unique dates in column J.

**then** put the following formula in **K3** to count the number of timestamps for each date based on the range (start/end).

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$J3,$G:$G,"Sunday",$H:$H,">="&K$1,$H:$H,"<="&K$2)
```

then drag and fill this formula to the right until **AH3**, then select from **K3** to **AH3** and drag and fill down until the last unique date in column J.

hope this works for you. you can always look at the example sheet above.
Let me know if you have problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am having 229730 rows this formula is not working

Comment: @krishna: simple: replace 999 with 229730 in the formula, and drag and fill down until 229730. i did it in the formula up there

Comment: it is giving same value as i am using datetime datatype which has date as well as time is it because of that,is there any thing i can do about this.

Comment: @krishna: what do you mean? isn't your sheet column structure like the one I sent you? what do you have in your column A? did you use my example sheet to check if it is working?

Comment: yes it is coming for some date then it is get same values again ,your formula is correct but it is get data from the start again.

Comment: @krishna: sorry, but you didn't answer my questions. Anyway, i checked it, it is working fine with me, make sure that you are following the steps in my answer. and also make sure that you adapted the formulas to your own sheet based on my example. one minor error could cause chaos. if you like, please provide a copy of your sheet, and i will make the adjustments.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gr0h02zmseifdqv/datetime.xlsx?dl=0 This is the excel file that iam working

Comment: @krishna: so in your sheet, you don't take the first column into account, do you?

Comment: @krishna: sorry, i am trying to understand the problem, but I am stuck. please provide an example or tell me what it should have been like that it isn't now?

Comment: @krishna: thanks. But still i don't understand the logic. You said you don't care about the dates. You want to count the timestamps between the ranges regardless of the date. The total number of timestamps between 02:00 and 02:59 is 2, one is on the 05/01/2014 and the second is on 12/01/2014. This is exactly what you want! Why should the count of sundays be 1?? whereas there are two of them in this range?

Comment: yes i dont care about date but i care whether it is sunday,monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday and timestamp where if sunday is already inbetween that time stamp then if another sunday comes in the same timestamp dont count it.

Comment: @krishna: i am more confused than before. Which sunday you don't want to count C2 or C9 ? why?

Comment: if i counted a sunday which comes inbetween a timestamp and then if again in the same timestamp if sunday comes i dont want to count

Comment: @krishna: so it means that you will only have 0s and 1s in your data, right?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why your using the dayname(E) instead of date(A) to look it up but this should work for you since the whole thing seems to be sunday

```
=if(COUNTIFS(E:E,"Sunday",F:F,">="&H2,F:F,"<="&I2)>1,1,0)
```

otherwise please provide more sample data

Comment: The reason why I haven't used the date is that I want to find the count where the time range is taken from starttime and endtime for all dates. The part where I need help is the count must be made for all dates on that timeline but if there is a repetition for a particular date it should not count again.

Comment: are you looking to drag the formula down and get a 1 in the first of each date that match the criteria of your looking for just a total count in one cell for all the data ?

Comment: yes for example date 1/5/2014 which is sunday and has a time 1:35 AM which comes under 1:00-1:59 ,so the count now is 1 and another data with 1/5/2014 which is sunday and has a time 1:10 AM which comes under 1:00-1:59 which it should not count ,another data with 1/5/2014 same day and time is 2:38 AM which is coming under 2:00-2:59 now the count will increamented to 2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of the formulas suggested so far address the requirement for dates to be only counted once for each time period.

You can do that using `FREQUENCY` function but it's best to restrict the data ranges rather than using whole columns, so assuming data in rows 2 to 1000 you can use this "array formula" in row 2

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(E$2:E$1000="Sunday",IF(F$2:F$1000>=H2,IF(F$2:F$1000<=I2,A$2:A$1000))),INT(A$2:A$1000)),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copied down the column

By setting up the `FREQUENCY` "bins" to be the date element of your dates in column A then any duplicate dates (that meet conditions) will go in the same bin, and the formula just counts each filled bin, hence not counting dates twice

Given the comments below I think this formula will be a better option for a month's data only

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(COUNTIFS(E:E,"Sunday",F:F,">="&H2,F:F,"<="&I2,A:A,">="&INT(MIN(A:A))+{7,14,21,28,35}-WEEKDAY(MIN(A:A)-1),A:A,"<"&INT(MIN(A:A))+{7,14,21,28,35}-WEEKDAY(MIN(A:A)-1)+1)>0))`

This will look specifically at the `Sundays` in the month and determine whether any of those `Sundays` have an entry for the specific time period, so the result of this formula will be **5 at most**

For a year you can use this version:

`=SUMPRODUCT(0+(COUNTIFS(F:F,">="&H2,F:F,"<="&I2,E:E,"Sunday",A:A,">="&INT(MIN(A:A))+ROW(INDIRECT("1:53"))*7-WEEKDAY(MIN(A:A)-1),A:A,"<"&INT(MIN(A:A))+ROW(INDIRECT("1:53"))*7-WEEKDAY(MIN(A:A)-1)+1)>0))`

For other days of the week you can change the 2 instances of **MIN(A:A)-1**. For Monday use -2, For Tuesday -3 etc.

Comment: It may be a little slow with that much data! I would recommend you try the formula first in one cell before you copy down, and see how long that takes - obviously you will have to increase the range sizes in the formula

Comment: I tried testing and it seems very slow, do you know how many **different** dates you have in the data? Is it for a defined period? Once you have the Sunday figures do you plan to calculate figures for other days?

Comment: Yes for 7 days and for one month

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that you have 230,000 rows of data but that only covers a single month?

Comment: OK, so if you have data for one month only the maximum number of Sundays that will have any data in a specific hourly period will be 5 (the number of Sundays in that month). Isn't it likely, with the number of records you have that every time period will return 5 (or 4 if there are only 4 Sundays in the month)? I think I can probably make a simpler formula, though.......

Comment: OK, I edited my answer to suggest a different formula

Comment: I am getting zero for the sunday?

Comment: Using that SUMPRODUCT formula? Do you get zero for all the time periods? Is the data still as shown, Date/time in column A - day as text in col E and just the time in column F?

Comment: If it need to be working in 12 month what i need to do ,any way?

Comment: It is in datetime datatype i will share my file.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gr0h02zmseifdqv/datetime.xlsx?dl=0 This is the excel file that iam working

Comment: I tried and failed to download your file - I think it's too big - can you just upload a version with a few thousand rows?